# VBA accessing files from a remote directory (error 76 - path not found)

Tags: windows, vba, excel

I have a remote server I have read permission (in Windows I labeled it as my X: drive)

The correct path to a file I need to access is:

> "X://some dir/some file"

The file that holds the Macro that is running exists in the C: drive. The code below checks to see if the path exists

```
If dir("X://some folder/some file", vbDirectory) = "" Then
 Debug.Print "dir does not exist"
End If
```

Running that above enters the branch telling me the file does not exist. My questions are:

1. Do I have to put the name of the drive shorcut? (eg X: or can I put //: instead?)
2. How can I debug in Excel if I'm even allowed to enter the drive?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, use backslashes for Windows paths. Second, don't use double backslashes when referring to a mapped drive. (Labelling the drive is meaningless to VBA.) eg:

```
X:\some folder\some file
```

If you didn't actually create a mapped drive, you will need to use the UNC or IP (and then you do use the double backslash) . EG:

```
\\remotehost\path\to\somefolder\somefile.txt
```

or

```
\\127.0.0.1\path\to\some folder\some file.txt
```

Comment: On my computer the drive is X:(\\ServerName\Folder\File) so do I just put X:\some folder?

Comment: If you mapped the drive, both will work. eg `X:\folder\file` or `\\servername\folder\file` The trick is that you can map a drive letter to a folder on a remote PC, so the path on the remote server might be `C:\folder\mapped folder\subfolder\file` but the mapped network drive (let's say you used drive letter M) on the local computer would be `M:\subfolder\file`. Assuming you have permissions on the remote server, `\\server\c\folder\mapped folder\subfolder\file` would take you to the same place.

Answer (score 0):

I think Tim is correct.

> How can I debug in Excel if I'm even allowed to enter the drive?

If you RECORD macro opening a file in your X drive. You will see all the code that you need to put your original code working ;) . Every VBA coder do that kind of tricks.